# A Non Well Formed Numeric Value Encountered In

Tags: php

```
$prix = $pkm*calculer_distance($dep,$ari);
```

please help what is wrong there?
when I try to run the code it says

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered

can anyobody help? thanks.

Comment: Have you tried dumping $pkm, $dep, $ari and the result of calculer_distance ?

Comment: yes sir I suggest to calculate the distance between two point and the price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$prix = (float)$pkm*(float)calculer_distance((float)$dep,(float)$ari);
```

Comment: if I change the code I get no more missing notice(Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered), but result ist 0

Comment: Thanks a lot I found the solution i giv just (float)calculer_distance und thats working ;)